# I am not able to open people picker

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to open ABPersonViewController directly.This is my code

ABAddressBookRef addressBook ;

```
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

ABPersonViewController *picker = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
picker.personViewDelegate = self;
picker.displayedPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)(name);
picker.displayedProperties = peoplePicker.displayedProperties;
picker.allowsActions = YES;
[peoplePicker  pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Comment: And what exactly does it do? Have you done any debugging with breakpoints or anything?

Comment: they show my orginal controller do not navigate to picker view controller.

Comment: yes we use breakpoint but full code execute picker is not shown

Comment: So this code doesn't get executed at all? So where are you calling this code from?

Comment: we use on tap gesture we used breakpoint the code execute but not shown. we print log after this which is printed and debugger move line by line

Comment: this is my full code

Comment: -(void)contactselected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UITextView *text = (UITextView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)text.tag);
    NSString *name=self.contactArray[text.tag];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",name);
   
}

Comment: is there is any appropriate code for this   my requirement i get name by tap gesture and after i want to shown it email id .

Comment: Please add code to your question not as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.

It was occuring because the account was disabled at Active Directory level.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.